# Operating System Debugging using KGDB tool

Tags: debugging, embedded-linux

I want to learn how to connect original machine with windows 7 and Linux virtual machine for the debugging purpose.

I am having windows 7 as original operating system and one virtual machine with ubuntu operating system.I want to connect them and try to debug using kgdb.
I am new in this so please give me some advise and right path to do this.

Thanks in advance.

BS.

Answer (score 0):

You can start from its [manual](https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/people/jwessel/kdb/). You can also check this other [guide](https://casper.berkeley.edu/svn/trunk/roach/sw/linux/Documentation/blackfin/kgdb.txt).